# Parse SDK issues with the new iOS 9.3 beta

Tags: parse-platform, mobile-application, ios-9-beta3

I have been having issues with Xcode since I started using the new iOS 9.3 beta update. I was using Parse SDK to support my application and now it seems it doesn't respond anymore to the iOS update and keeps giving multiple error messages.

Did anyone else go through the same problem? What is the solution to this?